# java equivalent of swfobject

Tags: java, javascript, embed

looking for a javascript class like swfobject to embed java and have a simple fallback if the user doesn't have java or refuses the security prompt.

thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could build one pretty easily.

Have something like a div set up like this:

```
<div id="java-applet">
Message to user saying that they need Java here
</div>
```

Then add [Java Plugin Detection](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/JavaDetect.htm) ([builder](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/PluginDet%20Generator.htm)) to your JavaScript. Then if that returns true, then do something like:

```
document.getElementById("java-applet").innerHTML = "<applet>stuff here</applet>";
```

Answer (score 2):

[appletobject](http://github.com/fjenett/appletobject/) may work, but I have not used it.

Answer (score 1):

Just embed the applet like you normally do and insert the fallback inside or insert a javascript snippet to remove the object: Besides param, you can add other elements, e.g. paragraphs with text or javascript calling some function to replace the object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function replace_object(x) {
    $(x)...
  }
</script>
<object x="y" id="some_applet">
  <param name="y" value="z">
  <p>java not available. some alternative here. <!-- option 1 --></p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    replace_object('some_applet'); // option 2
  </script>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

This helps!

I got a very strange problem while using applet to do batch file downloading from the server side.

The Ajax request seems conflict with applet request, the applet file downloading interrupted with some socket exception.

The applet works fine under JRE5.0, it might be caused by our recent upgrade to JRE6.0.

```html
<div id="java-applet"></div>
<script>
    var t;
    function startApplet() {
        var attributes = {codebase:'<%=request.getContextPath()%>',
                          code:'<%=appletClass%>',
                          archive:'applet/SignedApplet.jar',
                          width:0, 
                          height:0} ;
        var parameters = {para1:'value1',
                          para2:'value2',
                          java_arguments:'-Xms64m -Xmx512m'
        } ;
        var version = '1.6' ;
        var buildAppletTag = function() {
            var tag = '<applet';
            for (var attribute in attributes){
                tag += (' ' + attribute + '="' + attributes[attribute] + '"');
            }
            tag += ">";
            for (var parameter in parameters){
                tag += '<param name="' + parameter + '" value="' + parameters[parameter] + '"/>';
            }   
            tag += '</applet>';
            return tag;
        };
        document.getElementById("java-applet").innerHTML = buildAppletTag(attributes, parameters, version);
        clearTimeout(t);
    }
    t = setTimeout("startApplet()", 1000); // delayed
</script>
```