# Javascript library to reliably delay-load java applets

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I'd like to delay-load a Java Applet in the same way that [SwfObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) loads Flash SWFs-- you supply it a div id and it replaces the div's contents.  This would allow the whole page to load before the Applet starts.

However, I'd also like to use a best-practices Javascript library like [deployJava.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900861/javascript-library-to-reliably-load-java-applets) or [applet-fu](http://products.metamolecular.com/2009/06/08/better-applet-deployment-with-applet-fu).  The problem with these libraries is that they only use document.writeln-- if you use them after the DOM loads they will clobber the page.

Are there any Applet-loading JavaScript libraries that allow for delay-loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [java equivalent of swfobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178713/java-equivalent-of-swfobject)

In short, you don't need a huge library. If you don't care about detecting if java is installed, you don't need any libraries. Just add a placeholder and replace its contents with `.innerHTML`.